# Can't see any components on Github.io

Tags: reactjs, github

When I make a React project on [github.io](https://github.io), I can't see any components in Chrome.
In the 'myUserName.github.io' repository, there is a general HTML file. And a directory in the repository is my React project folder:

[image]

And the HTML file:

[image]

Like these pictures, `<div id="root">` is empty. But when I use it on `localhost`, it does run.

What could be the problem?

------------------- Add source code -----------------------

Directory :

__ index.html    (1)
|__ react __ space-trip __ build __ static __ ...
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . |__ index.html
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |__ node_modules __ ...
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |__ public __ index.html    (2)
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |__ src __ App.js
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |. . . . . |__ index.js    (3)
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |. . . . . |__ registerServiceWorker.js
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |__package.json

(1) project's index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>
    <div>Index Page</div>
    <a href='./react/space-trip/public/index.html'>Go</a>
    <a href='./react/space-trip/build/index.html'>Go - build</a>
</body>
</html>
```

(2) public/index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id='root'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(3) index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

After building this project and I added the url to [build]-[index.html], it's also empty.
I also tried running this page without registerServiceWorker, but it's same.

Comment: Please add your source code as text instead of image to your question by editing it.

Comment: Did you built the project?

Comment: Did you built the project?

Comment: Yes, i did. Is there a problem with the code?